# JAX-WS passing bean methods to clients

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, jax-ws

I have made a web service in Netbeans. I am trying to understand why the methods of the bean does not get generated by the client.

Here is the bean.

```
package OnlineAuction;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;


public class Auction implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private Product product;
    private Timestamp added;
    private Timestamp expire;
    private BigDecimal startingBid;
    private BigDecimal reserve;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param id
     */
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Auction)) {
            return false;
        }
        Auction other = (Auction) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OnlineAuction.Auction[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param product
     */
    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Timestamp getAdded() {
        return added;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param added
     */
    public void setAdded(Timestamp added) {
        this.added = added;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public void setAddedNow() {
        this.added = getTimestampNow();
    }

    private Timestamp getTimestampNow() {
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        return new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Timestamp getExpire() {
        return expire;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param expire
     */
    public void setExpire(Timestamp expire) {
        this.expire = expire;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the expiry time of the auction by adding the hours to the added date.
     * If the added date is not set this function will set the added date to current time.
     * @param hours to be added to the added time of the auction
     */
    public void setExpire(int hours) {
        // Set added time if null
        if (this.added == null) {
            this.setAddedNow();
        }
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(this.added);
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, hours);
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        this.expire = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public BigDecimal getStartingBid() {
        return startingBid;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param startingBid
     */
    public void setStartingBid(BigDecimal startingBid) {
        this.startingBid = startingBid;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public BigDecimal getReserve() {
        return reserve;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param reserve
     */
    public void setReserve(BigDecimal reserve) {
        this.reserve = reserve;
    }


    public boolean isAuctionExpired() {
        boolean expired;
        if (this.getTimestampNow().compareTo(this.expire) > 0) {
            // now is greater than expire date
            expired = true;
        } else {
            // now is less than expire date
            expired = false;
        }

        return expired;
    }

}
```

And here is the generated source by JAX-WS for the client.

```
package OnlineAuction.client;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for auction complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="auction">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="added" type="{http://OnlineAuction/}timestamp" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="expire" type="{http://OnlineAuction/}timestamp" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="id" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}long" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="product" type="{http://OnlineAuction/}product" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="reserve" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="startingBid" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "auction", propOrder = {
    "added",
    "expire",
    "id",
    "product",
    "reserve",
    "startingBid"
})
public class Auction {

    protected Timestamp added;
    protected Timestamp expire;
    protected Long id;
    protected Product product;
    protected BigDecimal reserve;
    protected BigDecimal startingBid;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the added property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Timestamp }
     *     
     */
    public Timestamp getAdded() {
        return added;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the added property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Timestamp }
     *     
     */
    public void setAdded(Timestamp value) {
        this.added = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the expire property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Timestamp }
     *     
     */
    public Timestamp getExpire() {
        return expire;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the expire property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Timestamp }
     *     
     */
    public void setExpire(Timestamp value) {
        this.expire = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the id property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Long }
     *     
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the id property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Long }
     *     
     */
    public void setId(Long value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the product property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Product }
     *     
     */
    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the product property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Product }
     *     
     */
    public void setProduct(Product value) {
        this.product = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the reserve property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link BigDecimal }
     *     
     */
    public BigDecimal getReserve() {
        return reserve;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the reserve property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link BigDecimal }
     *     
     */
    public void setReserve(BigDecimal value) {
        this.reserve = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the startingBid property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link BigDecimal }
     *     
     */
    public BigDecimal getStartingBid() {
        return startingBid;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the startingBid property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link BigDecimal }
     *     
     */
    public void setStartingBid(BigDecimal value) {
        this.startingBid = value;
    }

}
```

So why is my bean method `isAuctionExpired()` not in the generated source? I am able to cheat this by adding a `auctionExpired` property, but this is not how I want to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JAX-WS client is generated using the WSDL of the webservice. The WSDL only has the properties of the types that will be used for communication between the server and the client. So, you will never be able to pass the method implementation across server and client. The information in the below annotation is all the client class generator has while generating the client;

```
@XmlType(name = "auction", propOrder = {
    "added",
    "expire",
    "id",
    "product",
    "reserve",
    "startingBid"
})
```

This information is taken from the WSDL.

You have to understand that XML is used for communication between the server and the client. So, code from the webservice cannot be passed to the client or vice versa. The webservice and the client can be written in two different technologies. So, passing java code to the client does not make any sense if the client is implemented in any other language.
In short, you can pass information between the client and server but not behaviour.

Comment: Thank you very much Priyesh, I suspected this.